# Как задать стиль [class*=" icon-"]:before кроме определенного блока с ID?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой стиль:

```
[class^=icon-]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
font-family: fontello;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
speak: never;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: inherit;
width: 1em;
margin-right: .2em;
text-align: center;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1em;
margin-left: .2em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
```

}

Необходимо чтобы он работал для всех элементов на странице, кроме блока с ID="entryform". Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

`[class^=icon-]:not(#entryform):before, [class*=" icon-"]:not(#entryform):before`

Comment: Не работает данная конструкция

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3" id="black"></li>
    <li class="item-4"></li>
    <li class="item-5"></li>
    <li class="item-6"></li>
</ul>
```

```
[class^="item-"]::before,
[class*="item-"]::before {
    content: '';
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

[id="black"]::before {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Тогда только переопределять наверно...

Comment: К сожалению и данный метод не работает, браузер хром последняя версия.